# What is the best MongoDB client for iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, software-recommendation

Tell me please if there are any good applications to connect to the MongoDB for iOS (iPad pro). I tried to use online solutions, but they do not seem to be safe for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any client for MongoDB from AppStore should work equally well for derived products, mLab, MongoDB Altas, some custom servers, etc.

**Commercial Clients with a Free Option**

- [MongoLime](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mongolime/id1237825358) - Free version with one MongoDB connection

**Commercial Clients**

- [MongoMonitor](https://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/mongomonitor/id605373376) - not free
- MongoFly - not free

I suggest you take a look at **MongoLime** since I believe it the best (it has a built-in SSH tunnel), and I can get my job done with it.